# How do I prevent a user from using special characters in display name on DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do I prevent a user from using special characters in display name on DNN?

I have managed to get it right for username by using the below, but it doesn't work, even though DNN help text indicates that this field is meant to apply to Username and display name.

[image: Excluded Terms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Site Settings, tab "User Account Settings" you can find a setting "User Name Validation". There you can add a validation expression. I think this is a regex.

Happy DNNing!
Michael

Comment: Thank you Michael, problem is that only applies to username, I need it to apply to both Username and Displayname, thats why I tried to use Excluded Terms, which is meant to apply to both Displayname and Username, but any regex i use still only applies to Username.

Comment: Craig, the solution is to use the username as the displayname. In DNN <= 8, you can do this under Admin :: Site Settings > User Account Settings. Enter "[USERNAME]" in the field "Display Name Format". In DNN 9, the setting can be found under Settings :: Security > Member Accounts > Registration Settings.
For existing users you have to change the displayname using an SQL command, under Host :: SQL (Settings :: SQL Console in DNN 9), enter

UPDATE {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}Users SET DisplayName = Username

Happy DNNing!
Michael

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to restart the application pool after you made changes in the database using the SQL console. Also I should not call this a "solution" but a "workaround" ;-)